# Curl/python requests sending request with bypassing <!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->

Tags: python, python-3.x, curl, python-requests

I want to send a request to a site with curl or python's requests module but I'm getting 503

How to solve it in curl or python requests?

```
from requests import post

json = {"somedata": "somevalue"}
cookies = {"somecookie": "somevalue"}
headers = {"someheader": "somevalue"}

print(post("https://www.example.com/", cookies=cookies, data=json, headers=headers).text)
```

Output:

```
<html>
<head><title>503 Service Temporarily Unavailable</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>503 Service Temporarily Unavailable</h1></center>
<hr><center>Site</center>
</body>
</html>
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
```

It's same for curl too.

I just want to send request normally, example:

```
from requests import post

json = {"somedata": "somevalue"}
cookies = {"somecookie": "somevalue"}
headers = {"someheader": "somevalue"}

print(post("https://www.example.com/", cookies=cookies, data=json, headers=headers).text)
```

Output:

```
{
  "success":true
}
```

Comment: Btw if it's possible, i can use another tool too

Comment: The answer really depends on the particular site. It's up to the site to define what the exact request should look like in order to provide you with the data you want. Either specify what service you communicate with or ask the site provider for documentation.

Answer (score 6):

You might want to examine the source code of [the Nginx web server](https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/6a2e4098331077037cb9c197f88a54f46d870068/src/http/ngx_http_special_response.c#L42)! (Just see that link.) This source file literally contains this string message using the name `ngx_http_msie_padding` and it has that line six times. And this code is old already.
Further onwards in the same code, Nginx is checking if it returns an error page and if it isn't long enough, it wil pad the response with this additional string. Well, that is when you're using Internet Explorer or Chrome (Chromium) as a browser.
Apparently, these browsers complain when an user-friendly error page isn't big enough to contain some user-friendly message so the padding is added to fool the browser into thinking it is still user-friendly.
Now, because Nginx generates this weird padding, this also means that Nginx is noticing a server error. I assume that Nginx is used with port forwarding to send the request to some other running process and that other process might be down or unresponsive. So the 503 error is generated and with it you get the extra padding.
This means that it's still a server issue, or something like a proxy between you and the server. You cannot solve this in the client. (Unless the site crashes because you've sent invalid data!)

Answer (score 3):

The "a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page" error can occur for several reasons, including a temporary server issue, bad browser cache, DNS problems, and even issues with your servers.

The 503 code usually means that a server is temporarily unable to handle the request, so maybe it's not your fault.

Comment: it's not a server issue, it's occurring just when send request with without a browser

Comment: Any HTTP error code that starts with a 5xx is a server-side issue. Either your server is misconfigured, or it's not gracefully handling a bad request. If it works in a browser, but not via cURL then it's probably the a required header is missing, or maybe that some kind of security mechanism is kicking in. Either way, this question needs more info to come to a useful answer.

Answer (score 1):

As the other responses mentioned, the `503` HTTP status code means a "server side error" occured, so the issue is on server side. You have to analyze the server logs to get more details about the exact cause. Here more details on the different HTTP status code values:

- https://moz.com/learn/seo/http-status-codes
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status#server_error_responses
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_server_errors